# What is there no article before the word'Customs'?

Tags: grammar, articles

1. A man who was stopped **at customs**...
2. You will need to go **through customs** after you have retrieved your baggage.

If someone could explain this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

That is simply a matter of historical usage. "Customs" in the sense of "the examination of goods brought into or out of a country, and assessing the tax (duty) payable on those goods" simply does not take an article, and as far as I know never has. It could have been "the customs", just as it is "the excise", but it simply isn't. There is no rule, no why, behind this fact of usage.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are other similar cases where we don't use an article for locations when they're considered more like a phenomenon: I'm going *to court* (US and UK, I think); I'm *in hospital* (UK).

Comment: 'Church' & school would follow that rule too, or Youth Club, or Scouts - anything in that realm. 'The customs' sounds like you're about to explain how people do something differently in another country.